# Silver Mark Translation Help

Tags: translation, hanja

I have several silver cups that I recently purchased. The seller said they were brought back to the US during the Korean war, most likely in the mid 20th century. I was told that the mark is most likely hanja. I would like to learn more about the history of these pieces and any help translating the mark would be greatly appreciated.

[image][image]

Comment: It's written in 초서(草書), or cursive Hanja. There are few people who can read it in Korea nowadays.

The first character is 長. You'll get a more accurate answer if you post it on a chinese language forum.

Comment: I think only those professors researching old Korean history could read this... Koreans don't write or read hanja that much anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't Korean, it's Japanese. The characters are 「長翁齋・장옹재」 , pointing to the given name of an [Edo Period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edo_period) Japanese metalsmith/artisan named 「鈴木長翁齋」 (Japanese: 「鈴木長翁斎」, *Suzuki Chō'ōsai*).

If you Google image search "鈴木長翁斎", you can see some of his silverwork (and his son's work, who is self-styled as *Chō'ōsai the Second*, 「長二齋」 or 「二代鈴木長翁齋」). For example,

[image]